# Macro for image including

Tags: macros, graphics

I was wondering if there is a work around, or better way, to include images. I am using a simple macro that helps me:

My main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
    \input{images.tex}
  \begin{document} 

   Hello! Look an awesome image Fig.\ref{fig:AwesomeImage_1_22.png}. 
   \fooFig{AwesomeImage_1_22.png} 

  \end{document}
```

My images.tex contains:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DefinefooFig}[2]{%
                            \expandafter\newcommand\csname foofig#1\endcsname{#2}%
                            }
\newcommand{\fooFig}[1]{\csname foofig#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\DefinefooFig{AwesomeImage_1_22.png}{
            \begin{figure}[p]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image.png}
                \caption{Awesome Image}
                \label{fig:AwesomeImage_1_22.png}
            \end{figure}
 }
```

In my main content file I can include `\fooFig{AwesomeImage_1_22.png}` which helps me to keep my chapters clean and easy readable and small.

However, i have stumbled upon many forum posts that discourage the use of \expandafter! So i am asking if there is a better way to do this!

Best
     **-z**

Comment: What should the output of `\DefinefooFig{<image>}{<text>}` be?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should give some more information on the purposes of your command and provide a `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}...\end{document}` frame to work with

Comment: @Werner: Two reviews???

Comment: There's nothing bad in this usage of `\expandafter`. I don't think I've ever discouraged its usage. I'm dubious about the usefulness of this command, but you're the final judge.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: That's weird... I posted the comment and forgot to submit the review... Then you must have completed your review before I did that.

Comment: @zwck: So the output of `\DefinefooFig` is nothing by the creation of another macro that you can use somewhere else? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Werner It might not make a whole lot of sense, but I just like to keep all my "messy code" in a separated file. So I was wondering if there is an more elegant way.

Comment: You seem to be making it far more complicated than you need....  Don't you just want a command like `\newcommand{\insertfig}[1]{\begin{figure}... \includegraphics{#1}...\label{fig:#1}...\end{figure}}` and then use in your document `\insertfig{<filename>}` (where "<filename>" is something like AwesomeImage_I_22.png)?

Comment: @jon your approach is a very valid one and i admit i use it quite often, however if you like to include captions and other parameters the new command gets fairly long. it might turn out to be something as long as '\insertfig{htp}{imagename.png}{width}{label}{short-caption}{long-caption} ' and if your captions are fairly long it breaks, for me at least, the reading flow of the document.

Comment: @Werner: It's strange that you have 'completed' anyway ;-) Well, nevermind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you gain too much with this approach, but you're the best judge about it. I find that having the caption in an external file makes it difficult to modify it.

There is nothing bad in the definition you have, apart too dramatic indentation:

```
\newcommand{\DefinefooFig}[2]{%
  % define a new command to contain code for a figure
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname foofig#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
% define a command for inserting a figure
\newcommand{\fooFig}[1]{\csname foofig#1\endcsname}

\DefinefooFig{AwesomeImage_1_22.png}{%
  \begin{figure}[p]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image.png}
  \caption{Awesome Image}
  \label{fig:AwesomeImage_1_22.png}
  \end{figure}%
}
```

Just add the `%` in the places I did.

---

`\expandafter\newcommand\csname foofig#1\endcsname` is correct code; the token to be passed to `\newcommand` is created before `\newcommand` comes into action.

You could use

```
\newcommand\wordnewcommand[1]{\expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname}
```

and

```
\newcommand\DefinefooFig[2]{\wordnewcommand{foofig#1}{#2}}
```

but it's just syntactic sugar.

---

A slightly different approach that lets you specify the positional argument at run time, rather than in the external file:

```
\newcommand{\DefinefooFig}[2]{%
  % define a new command to contain code for a figure
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname foofig#1\endcsname[1]{%
    \begin{figure}[##1]
    #2
    \end{figure}
  }%
}
% define a command for inserting a figure
\newcommand{\fooFig}[2][htp]{\csname foofig#2\endcsname{#1}}

\DefinefooFig{AwesomeImage_1_22.png}{%
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image.png}
  \caption{Awesome Image}
  \label{fig:AwesomeImage_1_22.png}
}
```

Note that the `figure` environment is not any more in the code of a `\DefinefooFig`. This allows you to have

```
\fooFig{AwesomeImage_1_22.png}
```

for the default placement, or

```
\fooFig[!htbp]{AwesomeImage_1_22.png}
```

(any other positional argument will do, of course) if you want to override the `htp` default.

Comment: Thats a great addition. Is there no way to achieve the same macro without the \expandafter ?

Comment: @zwck No: you need to form the token before `\def` (or other similar command) sees it.